# Using py2neo not returning all relationships for nodes

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have imported data into neo4j manually and the import works as expected where all nodes have relationships:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/Hourly_Parsed/2019-12-05_00_hourly_parsed_mail_logs.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,c,row
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel1
RETURN a,c
```

Works fine every node has a relationship `match (n) return n`:

[image]

I want to take this to the next level and script the imports after the email data is parsed.  So I decided to use py2neo (version 4.3.0).  When executing and testing with `match (n) return n`, not all of the nodes and relationships have been created using the same cypher/day/hour:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
graph = Graph(ip_addr = '<ip>', username = '<username>', password = '<pass>')

query='''
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/Hourly_Parsed/2019-12-05_00_hourly_parsed_mail_logs.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
WITH a,c,row
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel1
RETURN a,c
'''
graph.run(query)
```

This is the output with random nodes without relationships.

[image]

Comment: How are you getting and visualising the output from the Python query?

Comment: I am using python to import the data then using the neo4j Browser to view the data via `match (n) return n` @Pablissimo

Comment: If you return `count(rel1)` from both queries instead of `a, c` do the numbers differ? What is the `FileHash` or `Url` property of any row that doesn't seem to have any relationships? (For example, sender 109574)

Comment: When I do it with py2neo i get 813 when I manually do it in the console I get 813.  When I run MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n on both I get Deleted 1450 nodes, deleted 642 relationships.  I am so confused.  It seems like they are the same but the relationships are not drawn(visually) on some when using py2neo @Pablissimo

Comment: Did you figure this out? When I use to_graph it doesn't seem to return any relationships.

Comment: @DanielDavee I did not ever find a solution.  I haven't worked with graph db's in a little over a year, so I may never know.